# Functions on arbitrary sets and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Determine whether or not the following function is injective and/or surjective:

$f: A \to A \times B$, defined by $f(x)=(x,b)$ where $b$ is a fixed element of $B$

$A$ and $B$ are sets, $A \times B$ denotes the set of all the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ as $x$ ranges over $A$ and $y$ over $B$.

My work for the injectivity is as follows: $f(x)=f(y) \implies (x,b)=(y,b) \implies x=y$ since $b$  is a fixed element. 
I am lost on the surjective portion.

Answer (score 1):

Whether $f$ is surjective or not depends on how many elements $B$ has. If $B=\{b\}$, then $f$ is indeed surjective.

You might also consider the case $A=\emptyset$. What is $A\times B$ in that case?

Comment: If B has multiple elements then is it not surjective? If there are multiple elements of B they can not be mapped to since any x in A is mapped to (x,b) where b is the fixed element of B.

Comment: @Student: That's right. If $c\ne b$ is another element in $B$, then $\Large\text{if}$ there is an element $y\in A$, the pair $(y,c)$ cannot be the image of any $x\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument for injectivity of $f$ is fine.

HINT: Whether $f$ is surjective depends on whether $b$ is the only element of $B$ or not.